# FreeNAS - How do you monitor disk/share usage?

Tags: zfs, snmp, disk-space-utilization, truenas, librenms

I have a server running FreeNAS. It has a built in RAID card that is currently running 4 disks in RAID 10.

I have a LibreNMS server that uses SNMP to monitor all our network, virtual OSes, and physical machines. I just noticed that when monitoring a FreeNAS machine it does not show disk usage. Not even the OS that is running off a USB stick.

Is this just FreeNAS thing? If so how do you monitor your disk usage to know when disks are becoming full?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I recall of FreeNAS, you actually need to enable the SNMP service from the GUI. There's a HOST-RESOURCES-MIB that should show you what you're looking for. All MIBs are located under the `/usr/local/share/snmp/mibs` directory.

edit:
Try a combination of these three OIDs (exact OID may vary on your system):

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.13
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.13
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.13
```

You will need to multiply the `hrStorageAllocationUnits` into the `hrStorageSize` and `hrStorageUsed` to convert to bytes.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yea, I have it enabled from the GUI and it is reporting but just not disk usage, at least. Maybe I am just missing some MIB refs as you point out.

Comment: Frank - I updated the answer with some more information.